# How to run tests using sure-fire on a POM package?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

My type of my project is a POM. I am using maven as my building tool. Currently the project just transfers things around but there is a junit test that I would like to execute. After researching, I came to the realisation that sure-fire doesn't necessarily perform well when the package type is a `pom` as opposed to a `jar`. I have fiddled around with the pom and can now run the tests using the following command: `mvn clean compiler:testCompile surefire:test` but I had to do a major botch fix to my test to make it run using that command. When I run `mvn clean install`, it doesn't run and I seem to get the following error:

`[ERROR] Could not find goal 'surefire:test' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1 among available goals help, test -> [Help 1]`

And this is the stacktrace:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.227 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-31T22:52:39+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'surefire:test' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1 among available goals help, test -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoNotFoundException: Could not find goal 'surefire:test' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1 among available goals help, test
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:290)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:241)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:169)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:131)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(BuilderCommon.java:96)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:109)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoNotFoundException
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can describe more in detail what you like to achieve? Making a Test in a pom which is packaging `pom` does not make sense, cause such packaging means there is no code at all (included test code as well).

Answer (score 0):

Add this goal explicitly:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And add the maven compiler plugin:

```
<plugin> 
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>                    
     <version>2.3.2</version> 
     <executions> 
        <execution> 
           <phase>test-compile</phase> 
              <goals> <goal>testCompile</goal> 
           </goals> 
        </execution> 
      </executions> 
</plugin>
```